# ¿Cómo acomodar un botón en vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Soy nuevo en vuetify, quiero acomodar uno de los botones hacia la derecha de la pantalla, pero al momento en que intento acomodarlo se mueve debajo del primer botón (INGRESAR), en px no me permite moverlo más allá de px -16 porque se pone debajo de ese botón que mencioné.

```
<template>
<v-layout align-center justify-center>
    <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6 lg5 xl4>
        <v-card>
            <v-toolbar dark color="blue darken-3">
                <v-toolbar-title>
                    Acceso al Sistema
                </v-toolbar-title>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field v-model="email" autofocus color="accent" label="Email" required>
                </v-text-field>
                <v-text-field v-model="password" type="password" color="accent" label="Password" required>
                </v-text-field>
                <v-flex class="red--text" v-if="errorM">
                    {{errorM}}
                </v-flex>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions class="px-3 pb-3">
                <v-flex text-xs-left>
                    <v-btn share @click="ingresar()" color="primary">Ingresar</v-btn>
                </v-flex>
            </v-card-actions>
            <v-card-actions class="px-10 pb-1">
                <v-flex text-xs-right>
                    <v-btn explore @click="registro()" color="primary">Registrarse</v-btn>
                </v-flex>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pon los dos botones en sólo `v-card-actions` eso los hace alinearse horizontalmente y a partir de ahí puedes posicionarlos donde lo necesites.

```
            <v-card-actions class="px-3 pb-3">
                <v-flex text-xs-left>
                    <v-btn share @click="ingresar()" color="primary">Ingresar</v-btn>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex text-xs-right>
                    <v-btn explore @click="registro()" color="primary">Registrarse</v-btn>
                </v-flex>
            </v-card-actions>
```